# what is the return value for NoSuchElementException while finding an element by accessibility id?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have written a test script in selenium. In it, I'm trying to find an element using accessibility id using the following code :

```
someUIElement = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('some UI element')
```

However, I'm getting a **'NoSuchElementException'** in the above line.

I tried doing the following :

```
if self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('some UI element') != None:
     //do something
```

However, it still throws the same exception which proves that the value is definitely not 'None'.
I wanted to know what value would be returned to the variable 'someUIElement' when this following exception is thrown?

Error trace :

```html
self = <test_edit_profile.EditProfileTests testMethod=testPreOrderForPreviousOrders>

    def testPreOrderForPreviousOrders(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(90)
        if self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('EditProfileButton') != None:
            manageOrdersCell = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Manage OrdersCell')
            manageOrdersCell.click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
>           if self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Reorder Button') != NoSuchElementException:

test_edit_profile.py:319: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appium/webdriver/extensions/search_context/mobile.py:47: in find_element_by_accessibility_id
    return self.find_element(by=MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, value=accessibility_id)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py:282: in find_element
    return self.execute(RemoteCommand.FIND_ELEMENT, {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py:31: in check_response
    raise wde
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py:26: in check_response
    super().check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <appium.webdriver.errorhandler.MobileErrorHandler object at 0x7fc1f00f62b0>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page u...11)\\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
        """
        Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.
    
        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.
    
        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                        value = value['value']
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if status is None:
                        status = value["status"]
                        message = value["value"]
                        if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get('message')
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    
        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
            exception_class = JavascriptException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
            exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
            exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
            exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
            exception_class = ScreenshotException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
            exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
            exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
            exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
            exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
            exception_class = UnknownMethodException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if value == '' or value is None:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
                raise exception_class(response, value)
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']
    
        screen = None
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']
    
        stacktrace = None
        if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                    line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                    file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                    if line:
                        file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                    meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                    if 'className' in frame:
                        meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if 'data' in value:
                alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
            elif 'alert' in value:
                alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: NoSuchElementException
======================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED test_edit_profile.py::EditProfileTests::testPreOrderForPreviousOrders - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given...
========================================================================================== 1 failed in 59.56s ===========================================================================================
```

Comment: Please share HTML in text format here with full error stack trace for better understanding. Thank you !

Comment: @cruisepandey I've added it.

Comment: is it failing for `EditProfileButton` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it's failing for 'Reorder Button'

Comment: @SriharshAditya Are you looking to fix the exception, or do you just want an answer to the question in your title?

Comment: Can you see `EditProfileButton` and `Reorder Button` on the same UI ?

Comment: @cruisepandey nope. They are in 2 different screens

Comment: okay. so basically your code is saying if EditProfileButton is not None then find manageOrdersCell  and click on it. Is it intentional to have nested if block `if self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Reorder Button') != NoSuchElementException:`  ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs within `self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Reorder Button')`. So if you try to use that in a condition or variable assignment, I believe the exception will prevent the above from even being attempted.

Answer (score 0):

That literally means that the element was not found.
It can be caused by wrong locator or missing / too short wait / delay before `find_element` method.